# When breaking on an exception, is there a local name for the exception object?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

When breaking on exception, in the local scope I see "<exception>" which is not a valid name. Is there some way to access the exception object in console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click on the value after `<exception>`, and choose "Store as Global Variable". Then you can play with the exception if you wish.

[image]